# Verifying HTML content at browser, without source code

Tags: perl, browser, mobile, webkit, cross-browser

I need to test a browser which is built on webkit. This browser is available on a mobile device.

Currently we are verifying the HTML content based on manual comparison on this browser againt the Safari (as it's build on webkit).

Do we have other best way to do it?

I am thinking from automation perspective.

Comment: Are you trying to compare the responses from servers to different browsers, or the visual rendering of those responses?  If the former, it's too easy, and if it's the latter, it's too hard.  I suppose you could take a look at the ACID tests, but they won't catch everything.

Comment: @bdares - It's the later one. it's visual rendering of those responses.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Amazon Turk to get people to say if a rendering is good or not in comparaison to your reference. This way you can get full automation for testing new releases. It will cost a little bit but can save a lot of time.

Steps:

- define a set of test URLs. You certainly have some already and you can add some pages from some dynamic sources (RSS news ...) to get a chance to catch new problem.
- Generate a screen capture for your browser one from your reference browser for each URL
- Add each image comparaison as a task in Amazon Turk
- Check returns flagged as different

Comment: do you have a url reference to Amazon Turk.